# Shield SIM808 EVB V3.2 charge a Lithium battery?

Tags: shields, gsm, gps

[image]

hello friends do you know if, can this shield (SIM808 EVB V3.2) charge a lithium battery directly or i need additional hardware?, I know that module has conection for battery but it can charge it?

Answer (score 1):

The module does not include a charging circuit for Lithium-ion cells.

---

**EDIT**

According to the [SIM808 Hardware Design document, Page 28](https://seeeddoc.github.io/Mini_GSM-GPRS_Plus_GPS_Breakout-SIM808/res/SIM808_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf#page=28), the SIM808 module **does** integrate Lithium-ion cell charging.

It states that the battery should have it's own overcharge, over discharge, over current protection, and reverse-polarity protection.

Comment: When I connect the power supply, at the  "Li-ion" terminals there is a voltage of 3.88 v, I think it may be enough to charge lithium cells without problem and the SIM808 shield has an AT command "AT + CBC" which provides information about the battery charging, that is why my question, if I need additional hardware? (protection circuit for Li-ion cells)

Comment: It would seem I am incorrect and will correct my answer. Documentation on this module was hard to find, but I have now find this document: https://seeeddoc.github.io/Mini_GSM-GPRS_Plus_GPS_Breakout-SIM808/res/SIM808_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf#page=28 which documents lithium-ion battery charging.

Comment: attached image about 
AT+CBC Command https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gaid1urp8wvk2j/Screenshot_2019-04-17-11-09-26.png?dl=0

Comment: @CarlosBravo every LI-ION Battery comes with protection circuit that protects it from overcharge and over discharge

Comment: @Vaibhav this is not true. It is possible, and rather easy to purchase raw cells, either in LiPo packs or 18650 cylindrical form which have no protection circuitry. You can/should never assume any LiIon cell has any protection unless you can verify that it's present. It should be readily visible in some way.